# How to throw error when Angular component @output binding makes typo?

Tags: angular

Let's say there's an Angular component with an output property `@Output() out`, when I'm using the component inside a parent component, I **mistyped** `(oat)='onOut()'` for the **output binding**, the CLI wouldn't throw an error, there's **no error anywhere**. How to guard against that so I don't have to waste time hunting for the typo?

Comment: Best way is cover code with unit/integration tests, to be honest.. :D

Comment: Actually it **throws an error** when you make aot (prod) build

Comment: OK. But the error msg is not helpful "Expected 0 arguments, but got 1" Anything I can do to get it to say there's no "output oat in this component?"